# parse yaml structs error

Tags: go, struct, yaml

I'm having the following yaml , when I try to parse it I got error, any idea what could be missing here?  im not sure how to struct the zone property.

T**his is the valid yaml**

https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator/cb42f23a

**Error:**

> error in model extConfigYaml: *yaml: line 4: mapping values are not
>   allowed in this context

```
type ExternalConfig struct {
    Landscape zone `yaml:"Landscape"`
}


type zone struct {
    zone models `yaml:"zone"`
}

type models struct {
    models []Model `yaml:"models"`
}

type Model struct {
    AppType     string `yaml:"app-type"`
    ServiceType string `yaml:"service-type"`
}

var external_config = []byte(`
Landscape:
  zone: zone1
   models:
    - app-type: app1
      service-type: GCP

    - app-type: app2
      service-type: AMAZON

  zone: zone2
   models:
    - app-type: app3
      service-type: AZURE
    - app-type: app4Í
      service-type: HEROKU
`)


extConfigYaml := ExternalConfig{}

err = yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(external_config), &extConfigYaml)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error in model extConfigYaml: %v", err)
}
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", extConfigYaml)
```

Comment: Most likely the identaiton is incorrect. If you remove one space from the beginning of the `models:` lines, it becomes clear and parsable.

Comment: codebeautify uses the deficient PHP YAML parser. Using that site, in general, gives you no guarantee that your YAML is valid if it parses there, and not if it doesn't. There is also no reason to not just include that small YAML document here in your question. Once the codebeautify site goes down, your question becomes useless for visitors here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error:

> error in model extConfigYaml: *yaml: line 4: mapping values are not
>   allowed in this context

There is an error in the indentation of your provided yaml content in which the `models` indent level should match the `zone` indent level. Along with that there is no need to create a struct for `zone` since it is a string value but you have assigned it a `model` struct which contains `models` data. Also you should export the structs using uppercase letters.

Modify your code to the code below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

type ExternalConfig struct {
    Landscape Zone `yaml:"Landscape"`
}

type Zone struct {
    Zone   string  `yaml:"zone"`
    Models []Model `yaml:"models"`
}

type Model struct {
    AppType     string `yaml:"app-type"`
    ServiceType string `yaml:"service-type"`
}

var external_config = []byte(`
Landscape:
  zone: zone1
  models:
    - app-type: app1
      service-type: GCP
    - app-type: app2
      service-type: AMAZON
  zone: zone2
  models:
    - app-type: app3
      service-type: AZURE
    - app-type: app4Í
      service-type: HEROKU
`)

func main() {

    extConfigYaml := ExternalConfig{}

    err := yaml.Unmarshal(external_config, &extConfigYaml)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("error in model extConfigYaml: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", extConfigYaml)
}
```

Working Code on [Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/brUqNpyYhYP)